# How to dynamic count how many times ng-repeat repeated?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Quick question about how to appropriately count the record that have been repeated in the view?

Here is the view:

```
<h4> Drafts </h4>
<ul class="nav nav-pills scrollable-nav">
  <li ng-repeat="solution in solutions | filter: {'username': username}: true | filter: {visible: false} "> 

    <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
      <h5 ng-click="editSolution(solution.$id)">{{solution.name}}</h5>
    </a>

  </li>                            
</ul>
```

And I would like to get the number for how many time the solution was repeated? The user can change the solution.visible value to true anytime, so I need to dynamically display that number.

I can use a variable in the scope to track that number, but I am wondering if there is any other better ways to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a temporary variable which hold the value of filtered result

```
<li ng-repeat="solution in filteredSolutions = (solutions | filter: {'username': username, visible: false}: true)">
```

Then do `{{filteredSolutions.length}}` to get the count

You could also use alternative way by aliasing the filtered result as @Claies suggested, that supported in Angular 1.3+

```
<li ng-repeat="solution in solutions | filter: {'username': username, visible: false}: true as filteredSolutions">
```

Comment: an alternative to this in angular 1.3+ is to use the built in alias `as alias` expression from the `ng-repeat` micro-syntax, i.e. `<li ng-repeat="solution in solutions | filter: {'username': username, visible: false}: true as filteredSolutions">`.

Comment: @Claies oh..nice this does make readable code.. I've updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you both of you! I used Claies' method, and it works great!

Comment: @Lisa Glad to know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is more convenient to filter data in the controller.
You can do it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl as ctrl">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="person in ctrl.people" ng-click="ctrl.hide(person)">
            {{person.name}}: {{person.phone}}
          </li>
      </ul>
      <div>
          Records count: {{ctrl.people.length}}
      </div>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
app.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    var self = this;    
    this.hide = function(item) {
       item.visible = false;
       self.refresh();
    };    
    this.refresh = function() {
        self.people = $filter('filter')(people, {visible: true});
    };   
    this.refresh();
}]);
```

This way you just have the filtered data in the controller variable and can use it to show records count.

Here is [jsfiddle with demo](https://jsfiddle.net/serebrov/6f24b4b8/1/).

Comment: Thank you for the demo! It works! But i used the easy fix this time. :)